# Find a triplet from three linked lists with sum equal to a given number

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list

> Given three linked lists, say a, b and c, find one node from each list such that the sum of the values of the nodes is equal to a given number. 
>   For example, if the three linked lists are 12->6->29, 23->5->8 and 90->20->59, and the given number is 101, the output should be tripel “6 5 90″.

This question is attributed to geeksforgeeks.

Looking for code review, optimizations, best practices. Please ignore reviews which include improvements to class / variable names. They are named so for personal reasons and well aware they need to be better.

```
class NodeLL {
    NodeLL next;
    int item;

    NodeLL(int item) {
        this.item = item;
    }
}

class LList {
    private NodeLL first;
    private NodeLL last;

    public LList(List<Integer> list) {
        for (int i : list) {
            add(i);
        }
    }

    private void add(int i) {
        NodeLL node = new NodeLL(i);
        if (first == null) {
            first = last = node;
        } else {
            last.next = node;
            last = node;
        }
    }

    public void setFirst(NodeLL first) {
        this.first = first;
    }

    public NodeLL getFirst() {
        return first;
    }

    public void setLast(NodeLL last) {
        this.last = last;
    }

    public NodeLL getLast() {
        return last;
    }

    public List<Integer> toList() {
        final List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (NodeLL x = first; x != null; x = x.next) {
            list.add(x.item);
        }
        return list;
    }
}


public final class TripletLL {

    private TripletLL() { }

    // this util function can be utilized independently, not just to find triple LL, thus kept it public
    public static void sort(LList linkedList) {
        NodeLL first = sort (linkedList.getFirst(), linkedList.getLast());
        linkedList.setFirst(first);
    }

    // this util function can be utilized independently, not just to find triple LL, thus kept it public
    public static NodeLL midPoint(NodeLL node) {
        NodeLL fast = node.next;
        NodeLL slow = node;

        while (fast != null && fast.next != null) {
            fast = fast.next.next; 
            slow = slow.next;
        }

        return slow; 
    }


    private static NodeLL sort (NodeLL nodeStart, NodeLL nodeEnd) {
        if (nodeStart == nodeEnd) return nodeStart;

        NodeLL midpoint = midPoint (nodeStart);
        NodeLL tempMidpoint = midpoint.next;
        midpoint.next = null;

        NodeLL n1 = sort (nodeStart, midpoint);
        NodeLL n2 = sort (tempMidpoint, nodeEnd);

        return merge(n1, n2); 
    }


    private static NodeLL merge (NodeLL node1, NodeLL node2) {
        assert node1 != null && node2 != null; 

        NodeLL head = null; 
        NodeLL prev = null;
        NodeLL aux = null;

        while  (node1 != null && node2 != null)  {
           if (node1.item < node2.item) {
               aux = node1;
               node1 = node1.next;
           } else {
               aux = node2;
               node2= node2.next;
           }

           if (prev == null) {
               head = prev = aux;
           } else {
               prev.next = aux;
               prev = aux;
           }
        }

        prev.next = node1 == null ? node2 : node1;

        return head;
    }

    private static void reverse(LList ll) {
        NodeLL prev = null;
        NodeLL curr = ll.getFirst();
        NodeLL next = ll.getFirst();

        while (curr != null) {
            next = next.next;
            curr.next = prev;
            prev = curr;  
            curr = next;
        }
        ll.setFirst(prev);
    }

    /**
     * Linkedlist structure changes, original structure is not maintained.
     * 
     * @param ll1       the first linkedlist.
     * @param ll2       the second linkedlist
     * @param ll3       the third linkedlist
     * @param value     the value, which individual nodes from a linkedlist should sum upto.
     * @return          the 3 values/items each belonging to different linkedlist, which sum to the value.
     */
    public static List<Integer> returnThree(LList ll1, LList ll2, LList ll3, int value) {
        final List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        NodeLL node1 = ll1.getFirst();       // node belonging to first linkedlist

        sort(ll2);
        sort(ll3);

        reverse(ll3);

        NodeLL node2First = ll2.getFirst();  
        NodeLL node3First = ll3.getFirst();  

        NodeLL node2 = node2First; // node belonging to second linkedlist
        NodeLL node3 = node3First; // node belonging to second linkedlist

        boolean found = false;

        while (node1 != null) {

            while (node2 != null && node3 != null) {
                int sum = node1.item + node2.item + node3.item;
                if (sum == value) { 
                    list.add(node1.item);
                    list.add(node2.item);
                    list.add(node3.item);

                    found = true;
                    break;
                } else {
                    if (sum < value) {
                        node2 = node2.next;
                    } else {
                        node3 = node3.next;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (found) {
                break;
            }

            // resetting nodes to first.
            node2 = node2First;
            node3 = node3First;

            node1 = node1.next;
        }

        return list;
    }
}



public class TripletLLTest {

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        LList ll1 = new LList(Arrays.asList(12, 6, 29));
        LList ll2 = new LList(Arrays.asList(23, 5, 8, 9, 10));
        LList ll3 = new LList(Arrays.asList(90, 20, 59));
        assertEquals(Arrays.asList(6, 5, 90), TripletLL.returnThree(ll1, ll2, ll3, 101));
    }


    @Test
    public void test2() {
        LList ll1 = new LList(Arrays.asList(12, 6, 29));
        LList ll2 = new LList(Arrays.asList(23, 5, 8, 9, 10));
        LList ll3 = new LList(Arrays.asList(90, 20, 59));
        assertEquals(Arrays.asList(12, 5, 90), TripletLL.returnThree(ll1, ll2, ll3, 107));
    }


    @Test
    public void test3() {
        LList ll1 = new LList(Arrays.asList(12, 6, 29));
        LList ll2 = new LList(Arrays.asList(23, 5, 8, 9, 10));
        LList ll3 = new LList(Arrays.asList(90, 20, 59));
        assertEquals(Arrays.asList(6, 23, 20), TripletLL.returnThree(ll1, ll2, ll3, 49));
    }

    @Test
    public void test4() {
        LList ll1 = new LList(Arrays.asList(12, 6, 29));
        LList ll2 = new LList(Arrays.asList(23, 5, 8, 9, 10));
        LList ll3 = new LList(Arrays.asList(90, 20, 59));
        assertEquals(Collections.EMPTY_LIST, TripletLL.returnThree(ll1, ll2, ll3, 50));
    }
}
```

Comment: personal reasons. This looks to me like you either named them that way because you have got some "namespace conflicts", or because you don't care. If you **know** they should be better, why don't you make them better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Naming**

Good variable, class and method names make it easier to review code, so I'm with Vogel612, why not make them better (although I think that in this case most of them are fine)?

**Comments**

- `setFirst` and `setLast` should be commented on. As I understand them, they are just there so that you can use them inside you program, not the way mjolka understood them? And in that case, they should better be `protected` instead of `public`.
- `node belonging to first linkedlist` and `node belonging to second linkedlist` are not a very helpful comments. What I would like to know in `returnThree` is why you sort `ll2` and `ll3` (why reverse?), but not `ll1`? A couple of words to what your algorithm does and how it does it would be a lot more helpful than your current comments.
- The comment of `returnThree` should document that an empty list will be returned if no result is found

**Bugs**

- `reverse` and `sort` do not update `last`. Fields like that really should always be up-to-date, or it should be commented on that they are not.

**Break**

In some cases, using `break` makes sense, but in your code, I'd rather do it this way:

```
while (!found && node1 != null)
```

**Tests**

- Your test lists are all the same, so just create them in `setUp`
- Test also with other lists (all lists have 1 element, ll3 has more elements than ll2, the last element of ll2/ll3 is needed as result, etc)

**Readability and Performance**

Some methods, especially `merge` take a while to understand as they are quite complex. If readability and maintainability are concerns, I would write it something like this:

```
private static NodeLL merge (NodeLL node1, NodeLL node2) {
    LList output = new LList();
    while (node1 != null && node2 != null) {
        if (node1.item < node2.item) {
            output.add(node1.item);
            node1 = node1.next;
        } else {
            output.add(node2.item);
            node2 = node2.next;
        }
    }
    output.getFirst().next = node1 == null ? node2 : node1;
    return output.getFirst();
}
```

If your main concern is performance, your approach seems a lot better (it doesn't create a bunch of new objects). However, when I timed it, my approach was about 3 times as fast.

Answer (score 1):

There are bugs in `setFirst`, `setLast`, and `reverse`. Consider this code:

```
LList list = new LList(Arrays.asList(1));
list.setFirst(new NodeLL(2));
System.out.printf("%d%n", list.getLast().item);
```

The expected behaviour would be to print 2, but it actually prints 1.

The same goes for this:

```
LList list = new LList(Arrays.asList(1));
list.setLast(new NodeLL(2));
System.out.printf("%d%n", list.getFirst().item);
```

and this:

```
LList list = new LList(Arrays.asList(2, 1));
TripletLL.reverse(list);
System.out.printf("%d%n", list.getLast().item);
```